# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE implementation/design

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I have a table, sessionBasket, that holds a list of the items in the shopping baskets of visitors to my site. It looks like:

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
usersessid VARCHAR
date_added DATETIME
product_id INT
qty INT
```

My add to basket script first checks for the presence of an item with the current product_id in this table associated with the usersessid and if it finds one, it updates the qty. If not, a separate query inserts a new row with the relevant information.

I have since discovered there is a condition ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but I'm not sure what I need to change to cause this to function correctly. I would need two keys here - product_id and usersessid, and if there is a row with both of these matching the ones I'm trying to insert, the update condition is made. I am sure there is a better way to do it than I already do. In addition, I check the product_id is valid in case it is spoofed somehow, so overall I make two queries just to check stuff, and then another to do the update/insert.

Here are the separate queries:

```
//do select query to verify item id
$check_sql = "SELECT * FROM aromaProducts1 WHERE id='".intval($_GET["productid"])."'";
$check_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check_sql) or  error_log(mysqli_error($mysqli)."\r\n");

  //do select query to check for item id already in basket
  $duplicate_sql = "SELECT qty FROM sessionBasket WHERE product_id='".intval($_GET["productid"])."' AND usersessid='".session_id()."'";
  $duplicate_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $duplicate_sql) or  error_log(mysqli_error($mysqli)."\r\n");

    //item in basket - add another
    $add_sql = "UPDATE sessionBasket SET qty=qty+".intval($_GET["qty"])."  WHERE usersessid='".session_id()."'AND product_id='".intval($_GET["productid"])."'";
    $add_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_sql) or  error_log(mysqli_error($mysqli)."\r\n");

  //insert query
  $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (userid, usersessid, date_added, product_id, qty, notes) VALUES (
  '".$userid."',
  '".session_id()."',
  now(),
  '".htmlspecialchars($productid)."',
  '".intval($_GET["qty"])."',
  '".htmlspecialchars($notes)."')";
  $insert_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $insert_sql) or  error_log(mysqli_error($mysqli)."\r\n");
```

Please no replies about SQL injection - my sanitizing is much more thorough than these snippets let on!

Any help shrinking these down would be fantastic.  It's possible my tables aren't normalized enough.  I was thinking it would be possible to create a new unique field which contains the usersessid and product_id concatenated which would collapse the unique indices into one instead of two fields, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need an unique index on `(usersessid, product_id)`. I'm not sure if you are actually using the automatically generated column `id`, but if not, you should change the primary key to `(usersessid, product_id)`. Then instead of running a separate `UPDATE` query, only run a single `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO sessionBasket (userid, usersessid, date_added, product_id, qty, notes)
VALUES (?, ?, now(), ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = qty + ?
```

Just to make it clear how the unique index should look like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sessionBasket_uniq ON sessionBasket (usersessid, product_id);
```

Or primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE sessionBasket ADD CONSTRAINT sessionBasket_pkey PRIMARY KEY (usersessid, product_id);
```

Comment: Cool, I'll try that.  Will making those fields unique not only allow one person to have a particular item, and no others?  This basket isn't for one user at a time, it could be for dozens.  I want more than one person to be able to have product_id 1, for example...

Comment: You will have an unique index/primary key on both columns, not just one of them (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html). It will ensure that there is only one row for each `usersessid, product_id` combination.

Comment: Great - I wasn't sure how that would work.  Thanks very much :)